# why i cant delete the row which i give by user input?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>


  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>


  <!DOCTYPE html>


  <html>


  <head>


    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


  <title>JSP Page</title>


   </head>


  <body>


 <sql:setDataSource var="dbsource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/ikart" user="root"  password="1311151011"/>
```

// these are my database linking code ihope that wil help you to solve my problem.//

```
 <sql:update dataSource="${dbsource}" var="count">
 DELETE FROM all_product
 WHERE id='${param.id}'
```

//i want to delete the row by jsut entering the id in the box//

```
 </sql:update>

<c:if test="${count>=1}">


 <font size="5" color='green'> Congratulations ! Data deleted successfully. 

 </font>
```

//used for alert msg for row deletetion...//
       Go For Update

```
    //for go back to update page after the row deleted successfully...............//   


 </c:if>


  </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that your code works fine and `Congratulations ! Data deleted successfully. Go For Update` is shown after I removed the comment from your JSP.

I have cleaned up your code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sql:setDataSource var="dbsource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/ikart" user="root" password="1311151011"/> 
    <sql:update dataSource="${dbsource}" var="count">
        DELETE FROM all_product
        WHERE id='${param.id}'
    </sql:update>
    <c:if test="${count>=1}">
        <font size="5" color='green'> Congratulations ! Data deleted successfully. </font>
        <a href="UpdateItems.jsp">Go For Update</a>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

If it does not work, then please tell me the error message.